# How to get MainActivity accessible for an Intent created in another class in Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to set notifications for Xamarin.forms project. Use DependencyService for platform-specific functions, define an interface with the signature of these functions.

My Interface is:

```
namespace MyProject.Interfaces
{
  public interface ILocalNotificationService
  {
     void ShowLocalNotification(string title, string text, string icon);
  }
}
```

and,the interface implementation is:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LocalNotificationService))]
namespace MyProject.Droid.Dependencies
{
  public class LocalNotificationService :Activity, ILocalNotificationService
  {
    private static int notificationId = 1;

    public void ShowLocalNotification(string title, string text, string icon)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    ......
        }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
       }
    }
  }
}
```

But, when I run the program, an exception occurs:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

An exception occurred on this line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
```

How to handle this exception and how to get MainActivity correctly in this case?

Comment: Instead of `this` try to use `this.Actvity` or `Application.Context`.

Comment: @CGPA6.4,Thank you for the response,I try to add like this,but Activity is not existed in either `this` context or `Application.Context` context..Any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure, but you try `var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;` then pass `activity`.

Comment: No,that also doesn't work

Comment: What errors are you getting using that?

Comment: The error was `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I tried this code, `var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
Intent i = new Intent(activity, typeof(MainActivity));` executing successfully.

Comment: @CGPA6.4,Thank you so much for the help,That's working. Apologies,That's my mistake. I've replaced this with activity in that line only and forgot to replace it in further lines

Comment: If you don't mind can I write it as answer so it would help others too.

Comment: @CGPA6.4,Sure that's very helpful for others also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Forms to get the `Context` of application in core `class` generally we use this code snippet

```
var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
```

Then we can pass above `activity` where we wish to, for example

```
var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
Intent i = new Intent(activity, typeof(MainActivity));
```

Comment: This lie works in activity but shows error of object reference required in xamarin form class. How to make it working? Can you pls help me?  `var portInfo = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TAG) as UsbSerialPortInfo;`

Comment: I also can't call Xamarin.Forms.Context. The type or namespace name Context was not found in the namespace Xamarin.Forms.